# Sass - Style parent when hovering on child element?

Tags: html, css, sass

I am relatively new to Sass so apologies if the answer to this question is straightforward. I am building a navbar component and would like to style the entire navbar (.main-header) when hovering over specific icons (.navbar-links and .navbar-title). So far, I have tried setting the .main-header element to a variable ($h: &) as well as using @at-root to no avail. Any and all suggestions would be much appreciated.

Example of the behavior I am looking for:

```
.navbar-links:hover
```

results in

```
.main-header{
  background: red;
}
```

code:

```
    <nav className='main-header'>
        <div className='navbar-title'>
            <a href='/blog/home'>
                <h2 className='navbar-title-text'>REVIEWS</h2>
            </a>
        </div>
        <ul className='navbar-links'>
            <li className='navbar-item'>
                <a href='/blog/home'>
                    <FaHome className='navbar-icon' />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li className='navbar-item'>
                <a href='/blog/television'>
                    <FaTv className='navbar-icon' />
                    <div className='navbar-text'>TELEVISION</div>    
                </a> 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pointer-events: none; at the header and set the children to pointer-events: auto; so you can manage it with hover like this:

```css
.main-header {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.main-header:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.navbar-item {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<nav class='main-header'>
  <div className='navbar-title'>
    <a href='/blog/home'>
      <h2 className='navbar-title-text'>REVIEWS</h2>
    </a>
  </div>
  <ul className='navbar-links'>
    <li className='navbar-item'>
      <a href='/blog/home'>
        <FaHome className='navbar-icon' />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class='navbar-item'>
      <a href='/blog/television'>
        <FaTv className='navbar-icon' />
        <div className='navbar-text'>TELEVISION</div>    
      </a> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```